# Unable to properly open html IOSlides output

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I have created an Rmarkdown IOSlides presentation. When I knit I obtain my .html output, I open it from the folder I've used as directory during the writing. When I send the html output to another computer or even if I send it to another folder and try to open, it appears has an empty document. What may I be doing wrong?

Here's the header of the Rmd:

```
---
title: "APRENDIZAJE ESTADÍSTICO"
subtitle: "Capítulos 6-7"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%d de %B del %Y")`'
lang: "es-ES"
urlcolor: blue
linkcolor: blue
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    logo: link_mate.png
    css: b.css
    smaller: true
    mathjax: local
    self_contained: false
    df-print: kable
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said `self-contained:false`.  That means you need to transfer all files concerned with the web page, not just the `.html` file.  You also said `mathjax: local`, which I would assume will cause similar problems.  Just leave out these bad choices, and change your header to

```
---
title: "APRENDIZAJE ESTADÍSTICO"
subtitle: "Capítulos 6-7"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%d de %B del %Y")`'
lang: "es-ES"
urlcolor: blue
linkcolor: blue
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    logo: link_mate.png
    css: b.css
    smaller: true
    df-print: kable
---
```

and it should work.